# How to compare two list of dictionary and update value from another

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list_1 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Owner" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "100", "name": "last", "email": "last@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]
```

```
list_2 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "52", "name": "abcded", "email": "abcded@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]
```

A preference dictionary `{'Owner': 1, 'Manager':2, 'employ':3, 'HR': 4 }`

- There are two list of dictionaries
- list_1 is the primary_dictionary, list_2 is the secondary_dictionary
- I need to update the role in list_1 dictionary if the 'email' present in secondary dictionary with respect to check in preference dictionary
- In the end output i should contain 'type' as in preference dictionary

If any emails match I want to update list one at all places with that email to contain a new role under'type'. for example if 123@gmail.com was in a dictionary within list2 then I want to change every item in list1 that contains 123@gmail.com as the email to have a role that is determined by a selection from the preference dictionary.

Expected out

```
[
    {'id': '11', 'name': 'son', 'email': 'n@network.com', 'type': 'Owner'},
    {'id': '21', 'name': 'abc', 'email': 'abc@network.com', 'type': 'Manager'},
    {"id": "100", "name": "last", "email": "last@network.com", "type": "Manager"}
]
```

Code is below

```
for each1 in list_1:
    for each2 in list_2:
      if each1['email'] == each2['email']:
        # Update the list_1 dictionary with respect to preference
```

Comment: Please, clarify the question.

Comment: e.g. what does 'with respect to preference dictionary' mean... what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: so if any emails match you want to update list one at all places with that email to contain a new role? for example if 123@gmail.com was in a dictionary within list2 then you want to change every item in list1 that contains 123@gmail.com as the email to have a role that is determined by a selection from the preference dictionary?

Comment: @JeffUK basically I need to update `type` in the primary dictionary if present in secondary dictionary if priority type present in secondary dictionary.

Comment: @EliHarold yes exactly

Comment: @azelcer, you got?

Comment: Now we know what you want .. what have you tried?

Comment: if its single dictionary i could have done like dictionary.sort(key = lambda x : preference[x["type"]]). since there are two dictionary every time I am ending logical error.

Comment: Why would it update '100' since 'last@network.com' is not in the second list?

Comment: @JeffUK if its not in list_2, what ever in list_1 will remain as it is. It wont update

Comment: @abd if what I explained is correct then your expected output is wrong it should have the same amount of dicts as `list_1` originally has, just with values changed.

Comment: what I described would expect the output: `list_1 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "owner" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "owner" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "owner" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "owner" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "owner" },
    { "id": "100", "name": "last", "email": "last@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]`

Comment: Just chaning all n@ and abc@ dicts to "owner" since abc and n are the emails in list 2

Comment: if that is not what you want please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following inputs:

```
list_1 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Owner" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "100", "name": "last", "email": "last@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]

list_2 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "52", "name": "abcded", "email": "abcded@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]

preference = {'Owner': 1, 'Manager':2, 'Employ':3, 'HR': 4 }
```

I would start by reshaping list_2 into something more useable. This will get rid of the duplicates leaving us just the "best" `type` for each `email`:

```
list_2_lookup = {}
for item in list_2:
    key, value = item["email"], item["type"]
    list_2_lookup.setdefault(key, value)
    if preference[value] < preference[list_2_lookup[key]]:
        list_2_lookup[key] = value
```

Then we can iterate over the items in the first list and use the lookup we just created. Note, this is a little more convoluted than might be needed as it is not clear from your question and your expected result what items from list_1 should actually appear in the output. I have tried to match your stated output.

```
result = {}
for item in list_1:
    key = item["email"]
    result.setdefault(key, item)

    if preference[result[key]["type"]] > preference[item["type"]]:
        result[key]["type"] = item["type"]

    if preference[result[key]["type"]] > preference.get(list_2_lookup.get(key), 99):
        result[key]["type"] = list_2_lookup.get(key)
```

At this point we can:

```
print(list(result.values()))
```

Giving us:

```
[
    {'id': '11', 'name': 'son', 'email': 'n@network.com', 'type': 'Owner'},
    {'id': '21', 'name': 'abc', 'email': 'abc@network.com', 'type': 'Manager'}, 
    {'id': '100', 'name': 'last', 'email': 'last@network.com', 'type': 'Manager'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that will do the following:

If any emails match update list one at all places with that email to contain a new role under 'type'. for example if 123@gmail.com was in a dictionary within list2 then it will change change every item in list1 that contains 123@gmail.com as the email to have a role that is determined by a selection from the preference dictionary.

```
list_1 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Owner" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "100", "name": "last", "email": "last@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]

list_2 = [
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "son", "email": "n@network.com", "type": "Manager" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "abc", "email": "abc@network.com", "type": "Employ" },
    { "id": "52", "name": "abcded", "email": "abcded@network.com", "type": "Manager" }
]

pref = {1: 'owner', 2: 'Manager', 3: 'employ', 4: 'HR' }
choice = 1
idx1 = -1
for each1 in list_1:
    idx1 += 1
    for each2 in list_2:
        if each1['email'] == each2['email']:
            print(list_1[idx1]['type'])
            print(pref[choice])
            list_1[idx1]['type'] = pref[choice]
print(list_1)
```

Comment: expected out is different with respect to your output